# Small: Setting locale

Tags: beginner, ruby, ruby-on-rails, i18n

I'm new to Rails/Ruby and I would like to get feedback on my little `ApplicationController` which is able to detect the visitor's language. I'm especially interested in optimizations on the control structure in the `set_locale` method (2 nested `if` statements and 3 assignments to one variable). I'm using the [http_accept_language](https://github.com/iain/http_accept_language) gem.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES = %w{de en}

  before_filter :set_locale
  protect_from_forgery


  def set_locale
    if params[:locale].nil?
      if preferred_language = request.preferred_language_from(AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES)
        I18n.locale = preferred_language
      else
        I18n.locale = I18n.default_locale
      end
    else
      I18n.locale = params[:locale]
    end
  end

  def default_url_options(options={})
    logger.debug "default_url_options is passed options: #{options.inspect}\n"
    { :locale => I18n.locale }
  end
end
```

Comment: Just a note: In Ruby, an empty string is `true`. Checking for `params[:local].empty?` is better than `nil?` since `nil?` returns false for empty strings, and the locale can be an empty string.

Comment: @Mohamad Completely agree with you on a technical basis, but I think you need to reword your first sentence because ```"" == true => false```

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say an empty string would **evaluate** to true, and not that it equals or returns true. Thanks for pointing that out. For exmaple: `{foo: ''}[:foo].nil?
 => false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in an "one-liner". Although one-liners are frequently associated with less readability, I honestly believe this is **not** the case. Something like this would work:

```
I18n.locale = params[:locale] || 
              request.preferred_language_from(AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES) ||
              I18n.default_locale
```

I see a few advantages in this solution:

- Your code will be a bit cleaner, since you can collapse 9 lines of code filled with `if`/`else` conditions into 3 (or 1, if you don't break the line);
- You won't need to allocate `preferred_language` in case params[:locale] is `nil`;
- And the biggest advantage of them all: clarity. The precedence of the options is much more explicit.

Comment: This is so simple and great, how could I not come up with it in the firstplace? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I like the one liner from goncalossilva, but I would probably add a check to the first clause.

```
def valid_locale(locale)
  locale if AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES.include?(locale)
end


I18n.locale = valid_locale(params[:locale]) || 
              request.preferred_language_from(AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES) ||
              I18n.default_locale
```

Comment: Good catch there, I tought Rails would fallback to the default language if the locale wasn't found, as a quick test showed I was wrong!